# Unable to stop ActiveMQ Producer?

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

I am unable to stop ActiveMQ Producer.

Scenario is:
I have set low values for memory usage and temp storage.

```
<systemUsage>
  <systemUsage>
    <memoryUsage>
      <memoryUsage limit="1 mb" />
    </memoryUsage>
    <storeUsage>
      <storeUsage limit="100 gb" />
    </storeUsage>
    <tempUsage>
      <tempUsage limit="50 mb" />
    </tempUsage>
  </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

Producer flow control is set to false

```
<destinationPolicy>
  <policyMap>
    <policyEntries>
      <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="false"/>
    </policyEntries>
    <policyEntries>
      <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false"/>
    </policyEntries>
  </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

Now broker has blocked producer and am unable to stop producer, Why is this happening?

***Broker Logs say:***

Stopping producer (ID:*Hidden*) to prevent flooding queue://test.queue.0. See http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html for more info (blocking for: 151s)

Answer (score 1):

You have not disabled producerFlowControl for queues, only for topics.

You would need to add something like this:

```
<policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false"/>
```

The link provided by the logs explains the behavior pretty much in detail. Your producer is somehow flooding the broker and the broker responds by blocking for some time.

Comment: I have disabled queue as well, sorry to miss out that detail in question. Even if broker has blocked producer, if I want to stop my producer I should be able to do so right ?